# Flash movie not loading

Tags: web, flashdevelop

I am in the process of replicating a current website. The existing site has a .swf for the header, and I've copied the code exactly as it is on the current site (obviously changed the location of the .swf file). The problem I'm having is that it won't load in the new site. I've looked all over for "Movie not loaded" issues, but most of them are resolved with things like out of date flash player. My flash player is obviously capable of handling the exact same .swf on their existing site, and I'm about to pull my hair out. lol

Any help would be appreciated!

P.S. I'm recreating the site in asp.net if that helps anyone.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Check if the SWF was trying to reference any external files on the server like images or XML. Sometimes the paths to these may be hard-coded into the SWF and would need the file to be re-exported with the updated paths (or just don't change the path to this file)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I actually put in the static url of where it's located on the existing site and it worked fine. I'm not really sure what I did wrong, but it's working.

Comment: No problem. Definitely sounds to me like it's dependant on other file(s) being in the right place for it to work. Maybe just something to be aware of when putting the new site live.